# Why is my local application not running on iis?

Tags: iis, google-api

Google auth window does not open for authorization on IIS.

I'm publishing my native app and moving it to the server. However, it does not work on the server (IIS). I request your help on the matter.

https://aycokucuz.com/

https://github.com/NortOfKing/TestYok

https://youtu.be/uMAEg4lHc88

Comment: iis version: 10
framework : .net core 3.1 or .net core 5

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.

Comment: The answer below clearly points out the root cause. If you want to learn more about the invisible dialog, you might read https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your code.  From the YouTube video i can see that you are using GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.  This method of authorization is designed for installed applications.  It will open the web browser window on the machine that it is running on in this case your web server.

```
 var credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                                                                             scopes,
                                                                             userName,
                                                                             CancellationToken.None,
                                                                             new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
```

What you want to do is change your code to use the web flow so that your going to be opening the consent screen on the users client.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...

    // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
    services
        .AddAuthentication(o =>
        {
            // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
            // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
            o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
            // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
            o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
            // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
            o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie()
        .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = {YOUR_CLIENT_ID};
            options.ClientSecret = {YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET};
        });
}
```

See full samples here. [#web-applications-asp.net-core-3](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3)